# Can I log-transform the sample variance estimated from an originally log-transformed data?

Tags: regression, variance, data-transformation, mean, coefficient-of-variation

I have a dataset that is log-transformed to meet the assumptions of normality. I have estimated the mean and variance of each individual. I understand that the obtained mean is log-transformed. My naive question is: In this case, the estimated variance is also log-transformed?
My next questions are:

1. The mean is already log-transformed and if the variance is also log-transformed, then can I do a second round of log-transformation of those parameters?
   Actually this is the method proposed for estimating the adjusted coefficient of variation to reduce the dependency on the mean.
   Here is the paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1161030118301904

I have got this solution related to my previous posts on the CV.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by a "log-transformed variance."  Obviously it wouldn't be the logarithm of a variance, because such logarithms can be negative but variances cannot be.

Comment: Is logarithm of variance different from log-transformation of variance? I applied log transformation to my original data to run the ANOVA. Then I estimated the mean and variance from that data. So in that sense, aren’t the the estimated mean and variance log transformed?

Comment: I am confused because my original data is log-transformed. So, if I follow the procedure in the above paper, I have to again take the logarithm of the mean and variance. Is this kind of a consecutive log transformation? Is it statistically valid?